# customer who have been consecutively paying

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am not sure if this can be done on PostgreSQL, I have a table with `customer_id` and `paid_at` (month when they paid) how I can find companies who have been consecutively paying for the last 6 month (since Jan 2018), and of those companies  which company has been consecutively paying from the day of their first payment `(min(paid_on))`?

```
     customer_id    paid_on
       14535    01/04/2018
       21828    01/10/2017
       52159    01/10/2017
       35033    01/02/2018
       1686     01/08/2016
       7347     01/02/2018
       33721    01/01/2018
       25789    01/07/2017
       62237    01/01/2018
       46184    01/02/2018
```

Comment: You can do this in Postgres but it is unclear what you are trying to find.  Are you looking for an initial sequence or any sequence?  Are you looking for six payments in a six-month period, even if they are all in the same month?

Comment: Please clarify your questions, add expected output. Why is this tagged with R?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am hoping to see 1-  which companies have been consecutively paying in last 6 months or (from Jan 2018). second of those companies how many have been consecutively paying since they sign up (the sign up is the min(paid_on).
hinte company can pay once a month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table payments(customer_id int, paid_on date);
insert into payments values
    (1, '2018-03-01'),
    (1, '2018-04-01'),
    (1, '2018-06-01'),
    (1, '2018-07-01'),
    (2, '2018-01-01'),
    (2, '2018-04-01'),
    (2, '2018-05-01'),
    (2, '2018-06-01'),
    (2, '2018-07-01'),
    (3, '2018-03-01'),
    (3, '2018-04-01');
```

The query gives you information on the month of last payment and the number of consecutive paid months in the last series and the number of all paid months:

```
select 
    customer_id, 
    max(paid_on) as last_payment, 
    count(*) filter (where sum = 0) as consecutive_months,
    count(*) as all_months
from (
    select 
        customer_id, paid_on, 
        sum(grp) over w
    from (
        select 
            customer_id, paid_on, 
            (paid_on <> lag((paid_on- '1 month'::interval)::date, 1, paid_on) over w)::int as grp
        from payments
        window w as (partition by customer_id order by paid_on desc)
        ) s
    window w as (partition by customer_id order by paid_on desc)
    ) s
group by 1

 customer_id | last_payment | consecutive_months | all_months 
-------------+--------------+--------------------+------------
           1 | 2018-07-01   |                  2 |          4
           2 | 2018-07-01   |                  4 |          5
           3 | 2018-04-01   |                  2 |          2
(3 rows)
```